# Can the US ask for Julian Assange's extradition without any official charges?

Tags: united-states, international-law, extradition, julian-assange

According to [this article](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-11949341):

> [21-04-2017] US Attorney General Jeff Sessions says arresting Mr
>   Assange is a priority. **No charges have been filed against him** in
>   the US but US media outlets report that federal prosecutors are
>   considering charges.

Since Julian Assange is not on US soil he must be extradited before being arrested in US. But there are no official charges filed against him.

**Question:** Can the US ask for Julian Assange's extradition without any official charges?

Comment: Extradition from where? The UK, where he currently is, Sweden, who'd previously asked for him, Ecuador, who's embassy he's currently in, and thus who's view matters, or some other country? These would be covered by separate treaties, which might name different standards and procedures (e.g. the current UK-US treaty has a relatively low standard of evidence for alleged offences).

Comment: I do not know if Sweden has reasons to ask for him anymore, since charges were dropped. I assume that the most likely country to get Assange is UK.

Comment: @origimbo Sweden has given up. Assange is still holed up in the Ecuadorean embassy because the British police have said they'll arrest him for refusing to had himself over (I forget the formal offence). He'd absolutely 100% not get bail and he fears the US would then try to extradite him.

Comment: I don't see why not. The US has never had trouble doing it before. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Dotcom#MegaUpload_arrest_and_extradition_proceedings

Comment: Arrest often precedes formal charges.

Comment: @Alexei: Charges are not dropped. Sweden is currently not bothering the UK to extradite him. As soon as Assange leaves the embassy and gets arrested for jumping bail, they will renew their extradition proceedings.

Comment: Is 'filing charges' different from 'indicting'?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Probably not; but it depends on the extradition treaty

Extradition basically works like this:

- Suppose we have two countries, Alphaland and Betaland. Joe Smith is suspected of committing a crime in Alphaland, and is currently on the territory of Betaland.
- When Alphaland makes an extradition request, it is asking the authorities in Betaland to detain Joe and transport him to Alphaland for trial.
- In effect, Alphaland is asking Betaland to **enforce an arrest warrant** issued against Joe.

So in the case of Assange:

- In the US legal system, an [arrest warrant](https://www.lawyers.com/legal-info/criminal/criminal-law-basics/what-are-arrest-warrants.html) requires a criminal charge. However, it does not require the charge to be made public. Individuals can be arrested on the basis of a [sealed indictment](https://definitions.uslegal.com/s/sealed-indictment/) issued by a grand jury, which may be unsealed at a later date.
- Whether a non-US country would be willing to arrest Assange on an indictment from the US (sealed or otherwise) would depend on the details of its extradition treaty with the US.
- In the case of the UK, the [BBC reports](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-16041824) a US arrest warrant would be needed; the [text of the extradition treaty](https://www.state.gov/documents/organization/187784.pdf) states "a copy of the warrant or order of arrest issued by a judge or
  other competent authority" must accompany the extradition request. The latter would *appear* to require a criminal charge in the US; whether there are any possible loopholes is a matter for specialist extradition lawyers.
- An extradition request would require *at least one* criminal charge; but of course, once Assange was in the hands of the US authorities, they could decide to charge him with any number of additional offences.

---

<sub>Caveat to the above: I Am Not A Lawyer, corrections are welcome.</sub>

Comment: I'm also not a lawyer, but since it seems we're talking about the UK, the Extradition Act 2003 applies, https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/41/section/70 and it looks like things can move forward either with an arrest warrant, or a certificate from the Home Secretary that a valid extradition request has been made, which requires naming an offence and providing "information" about it. This has made some people very upset.

Comment: @origimbo: Do you have a source for extradition without a US warrant? According to [this report](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-16041824), extradition from the UK to the US does in fact require a warrant.

Comment: The barrier in the legislation I linked to above is "intention to prosecute", which various groups claim could mean an indictment exists, but no warrant, (although as you point out, warrants are less common than they appear on TV) or even a lower standard than that. https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/117189/public-consultation-5.pdf. I suspect we'd need to be an extradition lawyer to confirm.

Comment: OK, edited again. AIUI, the controversy is because a US warrant requires "probable cause", which is a fairly weak standard of evidence and (arguably) lower than that traditionally required by the UK for extradition.

Comment: About the additional offences: In the case of Germany, someone who gets extradited to Germany can only be convicted for things that Germany put into their extradition request. So if a victim is in hospital and might die they won't ask for extradition of the perpetrator (yet) because they couldn't charge him or her with murder if the victim dies.

Comment: Things get really interesting now, because of the internet, because a person in Betaland can commit an act that is legal there to a target in Alphaland where it is illegal.

Comment: Not sure if this applies to UK law, but some countries reserve right to refuse extradition if they have reasons to believe that extradited person will face unjust trial.

Comment: @Miech: Yes, it applies in the UK. For example it took almost 10 years, and lengthy legal and diplomatic discussions, before the UK agreed to extradite the radical Muslim cleric [Abu Qatada](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/10164915/Britain-finally-deports-Abu-Qatada-to-Jordan-after-decade-long-saga.html) to Jordan.

Comment: @Kaithar : Extradition treaties usually require the act to be illegal in both countries; the UK-US treaty is no exception.

Comment: @MSalters exactly, which is why it's interesting... an act carried out on the internet has both the physical location of the person and the effective physical location of the action (the remote server) and in some cases a physical location of a third party (say, someone receiving some kind of data from the server or the first actor)... I think some analogy can be made to things like wire fraud?

Comment: @Miech there's also an interesting case that some countries (not UK I think) refuse extradition where the death penalty might apply.  That was one of the arguments as to why Sweden wouldn't allow Assange to be extradited to the US, but I think there was enough suspicion of loop holes.

Answer (score 6):

I think that it would actually be an issue to decide by the host country.

Since it would be the host country's responsibility to detain and extradite Assange, it would be up to it to decide the standing of the USA requests vs Assange's rights.

If we are talking about Rule of Law countries<sup>1</sup>, then it is up to its judiciary to decide if an extradition would be a violation of the subject rights or not. Which means that usually some charges should need to be filled in the host country legal system, and the judge should have to decide on its merits (they are not politically motivated, the accused may get a fair trial, that there is enough evidence for a trial, etc.).

So, if the USA asked for an extradition it would not be illegal for it to be without charges, but most<sup>2</sup> Rule of Law countries could not proceed with it without violating Assange's rights. But that would be a violation made by the host country, not by the USA<sup>3</sup>.

And of course, if the petition were to succeed, once Assange arrived to the USA charges would have to be filed at that moment; otherwise he could ask for *habeas corpus* and challenge any detention<sup>4</sup>.

**TL/DR** The USA may ask anything they want, it is up to the host country to decide which rights Assange have and to uphold the rule of their law.

---

<sup>1</sup>Countries without rule of law are easier, as they procedure is basically what the rulers say.

<sup>2</sup>I am tempted to say "all", but I am really not sure.

<sup>3</sup>Apart from the local legal system, there are international laws that would enter into effect if Assange could show that he was to be tortured, unjustly prosecuted, etc. in the USA. But even those issues would be addressed by the host country legal system.

<sup>4</sup>Assuming he is not put in the care of a Guantanamo Bay style "legal shortcut".

Comment: In most Rule of Law countries, the judiciary does not decide which rights the people have; that's up to the legislature. (Separation of powers). The judiciary merely applies the legislative decisions. Extradition is a tricky one, as the process varies. In some countries, that ultimately is an executive decision, not judicial.

Comment: @MSalters I changed the wording to make it more clear what I meant; OTOH you are right that in some (many?) countries the executive may decide to stop or proceed with an extradition but in almost all of them the judiciary may stop it on legal grounds, no matter the executive's position.

Answer (score 4):

Other posters have replied with good answers (both upvoted).
I am going to add some details, even though you did not ask directly for it, I think it may answer the spirit of your question.
The US may have (and most probably does) a sealed indictment against Assange. The US needs not and probably does not want to reveal what is in the sealed indictment, unless necessary or until it has Assange in its hands, therefore the indictment will remain sealed.

However, as soon as Assange were to be arrested by the UK, it has two options:

1. Require extradition using some loopholes as @Royal Canadian Bandit mentioned,
2. More likely, make a formal indictment to get Assange extradited

In other words, even if the US currently has no formal indictment, it can officially charge Assange at any time once he is arrested in the UK, at which point there will be no impediment to his extradition.